# Swordsplosion melee bonus meaning Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

In the "Tiny Tina's Assualt on Dragon Keep" DLC for the game, you can find a weapon called the "SWORDSPLOSION!!!!".  One of the features of the weapon is a ~500% melee damage increase.  Playing a Psycho in the game, it seems like that weapon should be insanely good.  However, it doesn't appear to magnify the actual melee damage of the Psycho.  The (now massively underpowered, but for the +200% melee damage) "Rapier" from the Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty DLC has been my staple weapon as a melee focused Psycho.  I can't tell what the +500% damage applies to for this "SWORDSPLOSION!!!!".

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm, no. The Swordsplosion does not feature 500% Melee Damage, but 500% WEAPON Damage which does only affect the damage caused by bullets.

The only prefix of the swordsplosion which does increase melee damage is "Bad Touch", which only increases it by 50%.

Comment: Marked as the solution - either the version of the game I was using at the time was bugged in the example, or I just had poor reading comprehension (I'm leaning towards the latter).

Answer (score 0):

I only know two things that could explain this.

(1) changing character mods could greatly effect the damage output of the weapon. Even to the point of unusability.

(2) Becuase this is Borderlands, it is safe to assume the "melee damage" modifier is actually reffering to *weapon damage*... since it fires swords...